# Convert objectID or _id from MongoDB Stitch query to string and map it

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, mongodb

I am able to query a MongoDB Stitch database, but I get different results.

If I console log all my data, it appears like this (note the 'id: Uint8Array(12) [ 94, 67, 83, … ]​​​'

```
item.find().asArray()
.then(data => {
    console.log("Found docs", data)
  });
```

[image]

However if I query it as an array:

```
      // Find database documents
      item.find({})
      .toArray()
      .then(xyz => 
        this.setState({xyz})
      )
```

Here is the data I receive, and state:

```
{
    "xyz": [
      {
        "_id": {
          "id": "DataView(12)",
          "get_inc": "",
          "getInc": "",
          "generate": "",
          "generationTime": 1581470496,
          "inspect": "toString"
        },
        "company": "AAA",
        "url": "http://www.google.com",
        "loc": "sac, ca",
        "gender": "female",
        "tags": "clothes"
      },
      "{_id: {…}, company: \"BBB\", gender: \"male\", loc: \"sf…}",
      "{_id: {…}, company: \"ZZZ\", gender: \"male\", loc: \"oa…}"
    ]
  }
```

I would like to grab the objectID (which should be something like "5e435320e45ce24954381c52") which appears to be a unique key of a "bsonType": "objectId" schema, and I assume I need it converted as a string (?), so I can map it and have it serve as a unique key for use later in a table ("Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.").

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Already is an [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

To get the string value just use `toString()`

```
item.find().toArray()
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.map(elem => elem._id.toString()));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively with aggregation:

```
item.aggregate([{$set: {_id: {$toString: '$_id'}}}]).toArray()
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#overwriting-an-existing-field

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/